# C++ vector array operator high computational cost?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, profiling

I have always known that the rich abstractions of C++ come with a certain computational overhead but I was under the impression that this overhead would be close to negligible once the correct compiler optimisations were applied. I was curious as to what exactly the magnitude of this overhead would be, so I wrote a simple test to determine this. The test is a templated function which takes a container variable, assigns a value to each element in the container and then sums the values across the container in a separate loop. This process is repeated for a preset number of cycles.

What I found, to my considerable unease, was that the vector implementation took nearly 3 times the standard array implementation. After permuting through a vast selection of compiler optimizations without any success, I decided to bite the bullet and eyeball the assembly code directly to try and see what was causing the time penalty. I included some assembly directives which allowed me to pinpoint exactly where the array indexing operation occurred and examined the code in detail. What I found, to my complete confusion, was that the difference between the vector implementation and the array implementation was utterly insignificant. The assembly code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/EuqfRya2).

This is the command I used to build the binary:

```
g++ -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
```

This is the command I used to build the assembly:

```
g++ -O3 -DTAGASM vectorArrayOp.cpp -S -o vectorArrayOp.s
```

This is the output I observe from running the binary:

```
gmurphy@interloper:Reference$ ./vectorArrayOp 
Duration 0.027678
Duration 0.090212
```

The results are unchanged when you include the computed value in the stdout stream, I removed them for clarity.  My system specifications are as follows (I've seen the same results on my AMD too):

```
Linux 3.2.0-32-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550  @ 2.67GH
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

The code follows, I would appreciate if someone could provide me with some insight into why the timings are so different when the assembly is so similar.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#ifdef TAGASM
#define ASMTAG(X) asm(X)
#else
#define ASMTAG(X)
#endif 
enum { DataSize=1024, NumTests=(1<<16) } ;
struct ReturnValue {ReturnValue(float _d, int _t):d(_d), t(_t){} float d; int t;} ;
template <typename Container, typename Type>
ReturnValue runTest(Container &c, Type value)
{
    int tagValue(0);
    timeval startTime;
    gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
    for(int i=0; i<NumTests; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<DataSize; j++)
        {
            ASMTAG("preassign");
            c [j] = value ;
            ASMTAG("postassign");
        }
        for(int j=0; j<DataSize; j++)
        {
            ASMTAG("preadd");
            tagValue += c [j] ;
            ASMTAG("postadd");
        }
    }
    timeval endTime;
    gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
    float duration((endTime.tv_sec-startTime.tv_sec)+
                   (endTime.tv_usec-startTime.tv_usec)/1000000.0);
    //tagValue is returned in case the optimising compiler might try to remove the loops
    return ReturnValue(duration, tagValue) ;
}
int main()
{
    int *arrayData = new int [DataSize];
    std::vector <int> vectorData(DataSize, 0) ;
    ReturnValue ad = runTest(arrayData, 1);
    ReturnValue vd = runTest(vectorData, 1);
    std::cout<<"Duration "<<ad.d<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Duration "<<vd.d<<std::endl;
    delete [] arrayData;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Since you never use tagvalue, the compiler might have dropped it for the raw pointer.  Are the results affected if you also `cout` the tagValue?  Also, your test is rather short.  Can you crank up the number of tests maybe 500x what they are now?

Comment: The results are unchanged when you include the tag value in the stdout stream, I removed them for clarity, the test results are consistent scaled up or down.

Comment: I tried it on my machine, and the durations are almost identical to each other. (~0.045)

Comment: Same compiler options?, what type of machine do you have?

Comment: Yes, same options, Win7 64bits, cygwin.

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.5.3. I have experienced performance issues with std containers in the past though.

Comment: In my case, the `vector` is only 2 times as slow as the array, but it is still puzzling. With `-Os`, the array slows down, and becomes equal to the speed of the `vector`. So that may indicate that some array-exclusive optimization is being done with `-O3` but not `-Os`.

Comment: `Duration 0.008792` vs `Duration 0.008828` for me, Linux 64-bits g++ 4.7.2, it might be a compiler or library specific performance regression that was later fixed.

Comment: Yes, it is COMPILER SPECIFIC, running it with g++ 4.6.3 I get `Duration 0.017721` vs. `Duration 0.081898`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, nice name, btw :), create an answer to that effect and I will accept

Comment: Run your own tests, and try different versions of g++, I wish I could give you a bug report where this was reported, but it's not something I know of.  I can post that as an answer, if you like.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, please post your findings and I will accept.

Comment: Note that while your vector gets initialized to `0` the array gets whatever was in memory. Also the order in which the tests run could affect the outcome. You should really run each mechanism as a separate binary.

Comment: Or run both tests twice in the same binary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
% g++-4.4 -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
% ./vectorArrayOp
Duration 0.008581
Duration 0.008775
% g++-4.5 -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
% ./vectorArrayOp
Duration 0.008634
Duration 0.008588
% g++-4.6 -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
% ./vectorArrayOp
Duration 0.01731
Duration 0.081696
% g++-4.7 -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
% ./vectorArrayOp
Duration 0.008618
Duration 0.008612
% clang++ -O3 vectorArrayOp.cpp -o vectorArrayOp
% ./vectorArrayOp
Duration 0.066484
Duration 0.066435
```

Based on these results, this is probably a compiler specific performance regression in g++ 4.6.

Comment: As an aside, I want to know wtf is going on with clang in this test.

Comment: clang still has a long way to go with optimisations, unfortunately.