# Migrating from C++03 to C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What breaking changes are introduced in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11)

I've read many things about C++11 or C++0x and currently, I have 2 average size projects under development.

One of them uses Qt framework and another uses Poco. In both of them we're using GCC with default mode (C++03).

I think both of Qt and Poco have written in C++03 specifications, but I wonder if is it OK to enable `--std=c++0x` in our projects and use new features without any special incompatibilities?

Does someone have any experiment to use large C++03-libraries (specially Qt and Poco) within C++11 projects and face to some issues, if yes, which issues?

***Note: This is not a duplicated question. I'm specially speaking about two famous frameworks Qt and Poco. Someone may say "In my experience, Don't use X class of Qt with this Y new feature of C++11...."***

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11)

Comment: https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/26/cpp0x-in-qt/

Comment: What compiler version are you using? the `-std=c++0x` seems to indicate an old version, in which case it might be painful to find issues that have been corrected/changed or fight partial support for the features

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: gcc 4.6.2

Comment: GCC 4.6 is getting pretty old, and moreover it has performance regressions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238183/c-vector-array-operator-high-computational-cost/13238513#13238513  You should update irrespective.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: Useful, I will upgrade my GCC